# Switch Negative Sign from Back to Front of Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 fields in my SQL table that are currently `VARCHAR` fields. The data in these fields are money amounts, but the negative values have the sign at the end of the number, rather than the front.

**Example**: 4.56-

How can I change these fields from `VARCHAR` to `MONEY` and switch the negative sign to the front of the values in the process?

I have tried `CAST([FIELD_NAME] AS MONEY)` but that hasn't worked. I have gotten the following error from this attempt:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect
>   syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detect the minus sign; remove it; cast the positive result to MONEY; and negate it.

```
CASE WHEN [FIELD_NAME] LIKE '%-' 
     THEN -(cast(replace([FIELD_NAME],'-','') AS money)) 
     ELSE cast([FIELD_NAME] AS money) 
     END
```

Comment: Personally I would prefer a more explict "-1 *" instead of - which can easily go unnoticed. But regardless this should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @S varchar(25) = '4.59-'

Select try_convert(money,iif(charindex('-',@s)>0,'-','')+replace(@S,'-',''))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of adding back the minus sign *inside* the convert. I like it.

Comment: @RossPresser Not any better than your answer.  It is just where my lizard brain brought me  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @FIELD_NAME VARCHAR(MAX) = '4.56-'

SELECT IIF(RIGHT(@FIELD_NAME, 1) = '-', 
           -1 * CAST(LEFT(@FIELD_NAME, LEN(@FIELD_NAME)-1) AS MONEY), 
           CAST(@FIELD_NAME AS MONEY))
```